# Handling user security scope with nHibernate or other ORM

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, nhibernate, orm

How should one handle the situation where you may need to filter by a group of users.
Here is the scenario.

I have an administrator role in my company. I should be able to see all the data belonging to me plus all the other users who I have control over.

A plain old user however should only be able to access their own data.

If you are writing regular sql statements then you can have a security table with every user and who they have access too but i'm not sure how to handle this situation in the OO and ORM world.

Any one dealt with this scenario in a web application using an ORM?
Would love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Your database design should be the same regardless of whether or not you're using an ORM. That said, you need to post a table structure and someone will help you write the proper c# code using nHibernate to return the desired query.

Comment: @Spencer Ruport. I don't agree, because I generate my database schema with an ORM. The C# code should be the same, and the database design should be what's optimal for the specific ORM.

Comment: @Paco - So you optimize for a tool instead of application performance? Perhaps it's a matter of opinion but that seems backwards to me.

Comment: @Spencer. Yes it is the backwards approach. I don't optimize for a tool or application performance, but for the easiest to write and easiest to read code (and as much tool independent as possible). I measure the application performance with a profiler and change the parts that are too slow (less than 1% of the code). Optimizing for performance can make the code less flexible some times. I only optimize performance when measured too slow to keep the code as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe NHibernate [Filters](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#filters) will help you with that.